# Why is my code not printing anything? Is there something wrong with my loops?

Tags: java

I have the following code in a project called PostOffice:

```
package project;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PostOffice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("User input: ");
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    String[] determineinput=input.split(",");
    String regular="Regular Postcard";
    String large="Large Postcard";
    String envelope="Envelope";
    String largeenvenlope="Large Envelope";
    String packagee="Package";
    String largepackage="Large Package";
    String unmailable="Unmailable";
    if(3.5<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<4.25){ 
        if(3.5<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<6){
            if(0.007<Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]) && Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.016){
                System.out.println(regular);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(4.25<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<6){
        if(6<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<11.5){
            if(0.007<Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]) && Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.016){
                System.out.println(large);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(3.5<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<6.125){
            if(5<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<11.5){
                if(0.25<Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]) && Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.5){
                    System.out.println(envelope);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(6.125<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<24){
        if(11<Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]) && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<18){
            if(0.25<Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]) && Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.5){
                System.out.println(largeenvenlope);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<6.125 || Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])>24){
        if(Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<11 || Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])>18){
            if(Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.25 || Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])>0.5){
                if((Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])*2+Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])*2)<=84){
                    System.out.println(packagee);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<6.125 || Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])>24){
        if(Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<11 || Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])>18){
            if(Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.25 || Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])>0.5){
                if((Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])+Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]))>84 && (Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])+Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1]))<130){
                    System.out.println(largepackage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if((Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])<3.5 || Integer.parseInt(determineinput[0])>24) && (Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])<0.07 && Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2])>0.25) && (Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])<3.5 && Integer.parseInt(determineinput[1])>18)){
        System.out.println(unmailable);
    }
}
```

}

But when I run it, it prints nothing. It just says`<terminated>` and the output is blank. I tried fixing it and ran it several times over and over again, but the result is the same. Is there something wrong with my code? If so, what can I do to resolve it? And how would I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: What is your input and expected result? when I provided input `2,3,5`, it printed `Package`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are comparing parsed integers to floating-point values?

Comment: Your program would be *orders of magnitude* easier to read if you would parse each element of `determineinput` *once,* before attempting any `if`-tests, and store them in variables.  For instance, `double width = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[0]);`  Note that Integer.parseInt returns an integer, so the only way the result can be in the range [3.5, 4.25) is if it is exactly 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `<terminated>` because your input doesn't match any `if` condition, so the program terminates with no output. Add a simple print at the end of your main function to report when there is no match like:

```java
System.out.println("Input doesn't match any result");
```

Also as mentioned in the comment, parse the input at the beginning and then process it. I refactored your code:

```java
// ...
double height = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[0]);
double length = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[1]);
double thickness = Double.parseDouble(determineinput[2]);

if (3.5 < height && height < 4.25) {
    if (3.5 < length && length < 6) {
        if (0.007 < thickness  && thickness < 0.016) {
            System.out.println(regular);
        }
    }
} else if (4.25 < height && height < 6) {
    if (6 < length && length < 11.5) {
        if (0.007 < thickness && thickness < 0.016) {
            System.out.println(large);
        }
    }
} else if (3.5 < height && height < 6.125) {
    if (5 < length && length < 11.5) {
        if (0.25 < thickness && thickness < 0.5) {
            System.out.println(envelope);
        }
    }
} else if (6.125 < height && height < 24) {
    if (11 < length && length < 18) {
        if (0.25 < thickness  && thickness < 0.5) {
            System.out.println(largeenvenlope);
        }
    }
} else if (height < 6.125 || height > 24) {
    if (length < 11 || length > 18) {
        if (thickness < 0.25 || thickness > 0.5) {
            if ((height * 2 + length * 2) <= 84) {
                System.out.println(packagee);
            }
        }
    }
} else if (height < 6.125 || height > 24) {
    if (length < 11 || length > 18) {
        if (thickness < 0.25 || thickness > 0.5) {
            if ((height + length) > 84 && (height + length) < 130) {
                System.out.println(largepackage);
            }
        }
    }
}
if ((height < 3.5 || height > 24)
        && (thickness < 0.07 || thickness > 0.25)
        && (length < 3.5 || length > 18)) {
    System.out.println(unmailable);
}
System.out.println("Input doesn't match any result");
```

Comment: A couple of observations.  I find that instead of  `6.125 < height && height < 24` it is clearer to say `height > 6.125 && height < 24`.  But that is my preference and perhaps not the OPs.  And you may want to change `lenght` to `length`.  And  your final check has problems.  For example.  `(lenght < 3.5 && lenght > 18)`  and another similar one can never be true so the whole expression can never be true.

Comment: @WJS thanks for the heads-up, I rushed the answer earlier today. I'll fix it but I think OP isn't following the post anymore.

Comment: I took your advice but when I compile it I get an exception. It says: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at project.PostOffice.main(PostOffice.java:8)

Comment: The error says *No line found*, maybe you haven't provided the input